# Accessing keys in dictionaries

Tags: python, key, dictionary

If I wanted to access all the keys in a dictionary and check if the sequences like (ATGC) which is the key have "GC". How could I access the keys to check if it contains the string "GC"?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Keys are unique, so wouldn't it always be at most one?

Comment: So if I have a bunch of keys like ATGC, AATT, GGGC, TATA.. I want to know how many keys have GC in it. Can I do this?

Comment: Your first sentence doesn't make sense.  Specifically this part: `and check if the sequences like (ATGC) which is the key have "GC".`

Comment: @JonathanVanasco my keys are 4 base pairs DNA sequences and I wanted to calculate the GC percent so I want to know how many DNA sequence keys contain GC in them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
matches = [ k for k in yourdictionary.keys() if 'gc' in k.lower() ]
number_of_matches = len(matches)
```

you could also do a `regex` or `string.find` ( returns -1 if not found ) or `string.count` -- but `if substring in string` works and is cleaner to illustrate the point.  i also cast the key to lowercase and compared against a lowercase string, so it would effectively do a case insensitive match.

Comment: If I wanted to calculate how many GC were found based on the matches would I do GCpercent = (number_of_matches/len(yourdictionary))*100 ?

Comment: i think that would work on python 3.  under python 2.x you'd need to convert the numbers to floats first.  see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5998010/442650  and http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1439189