# code that count the amount of yes and no in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to create a program for the following:

Create a function in Python named `vote_pourcentage` which takes as
input a `string` and `counts` the number of `yes` and `no` in this chain . There
It should return the percentage of `yes` from all `yes` and `no` , not counting abstentions in the string. ( It may be considered that the string only contains
`yes`, `no` or `abstention` and there is at least one yes or no ).

In the main part of the Python program , ask the user to insert the string
characters , invoke the `vote_pourcentage` function and display the result of the vote. There are many messages to display.

1. If all votes are `yes` (excluding abstentions), print
   `unanimously`
2. if at least 2/3 of the votes are `yes`, print `clear majority`
3. and if at least half of votes are `yes` , print `simple majority`;
4. otherwise print `the motion does not pass`.

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: My question is how to do start because I have no clue how and yes its a exercise given in class

Answer (score 3):

Way you can start is to split your exercise into logical parts and use google (or SO search) to solve each part.

For example,

> Create a function in Python named vote_pourcentage which takes as input a string and counts the number of yes and no in this chain .

"python create function":
[How to define and call function](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm)

"python count in string":
[Count number of occurrences of a given substring in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899905/count-number-of-occurrences-of-a-given-substring-in-a-string)

> There It should return the percentage of yes from all yes and no , not
>   counting abstentions in the string.

"python count percentage":
[Calculate Percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997987/is-there-an-operator-to-calculate-percentage-in-python)

and so on.